# Having trouble passing data between client and server in eclipse: nosuchelementexception

Tags: java, sockets, exception, networking, nosuchelementexception

I've a bank account program where users can add, withdraw money and view account details. I'm trying to send this data back and forth between the client and the server. I'm getting a connection but I'm not able to send data back and forth. I've gotten a `nosuchelementexception` for every line where I use my `Scanner` object for getting values from the server :
`Scanner sScan = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());`
Is it the right way for passing data back and forth?

**Here's the client:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        {
            String user_name=null,type,temp;
            type = null;
            int balance=0,tmp=0,temp1=0;
            int withdraw=0,currentBal=0;
            int randNumber = 0; 
randNumber = (int)((Math.random() * 9000)+1000); 

            create_account user = new create_account("user",0,"savings"); 

                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner strng=new Scanner(System.in);
                try{
                    //new socket for communicatio
                Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
                //scanner for accepting data from serve
                Scanner sScan = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
                //new printstream for passing values to server
                PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                 System.out.println("Connected");


                int userChoice;
                boolean quit = false;
                 System.out.println("Welcome to UNCC Banking, please select from the menu");

                do {
                    //present menu
                      System.out.println("1. Deposit money");
                      System.out.println("2. Withdraw money");
                      System.out.println("3. Check balance");
                      System.out.println("4. Display Account Details");
                      System.out.println("0. to quit: \n");
                      System.out.print("Enter Your Choice : ");
                      //send userChoice to Server?
                      userChoice = in.nextInt();

                      //p.println(userChoice);
                      //get number from server?
                     // temp1 = sScan.nextInt();
                      switch (userChoice) {



                    case 1: // deposit

                        //p.println(tmp);
                       //temp1 = sScan.nextInt();
                     System.out.print("Enter Amount Of Money : ");
                     //balance=in.nextInt();
                     p.println(balance);
                     temp1 = sScan.nextInt();
                     user.Acc_Balance=balance;
                     System.out.println("\t Successfully Deposited.");


                       break;

                      case 2: // withdraw money                      


                                 if(user.Acc_Balance==0)
                                 System.out.print("Your Account is Empty.");

                                 else{
                                 System.out.print("Enter Amout Of Money : ");   
                                 //withdraw=in.nextInt();  
                                 p.println(withdraw);
                                 temp1=sScan.nextInt();

                                 if(withdraw>user.Acc_Balance){
                                 System.out.print("Please enter Valid Amout of Money : ");
                                 //withdraw=in.nextInt();
                                 p.println(withdraw);
                                 temp1=sScan.nextInt();

                                 }
                                 else
                                 currentBal= user.withdraw(withdraw);

                                 System.out.println("Your Current Balance : "+currentBal); 
                                 p.println(currentBal);
                                 }


                            break;

                      case 4: // check balance 

                                 System.out.println("Your Current Balance : "+user.Acc_Balance);
                                 p.println(user.Acc_Balance);

                          break;

                      case 5: // display account info 

                                 user.display_details();                             


                          break;
                      case 0:
                            quit = true;
                            break;
                      default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
                            break;
                      }
                      System.out.println("\n");
                } while (!quit);
                System.out.println("Thank you for visiting UNCC Banking");

         }

        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    } 

}
```

**Here's the server:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

class BankAccount  {
    String name,acc_type;

    int Acc_Balance;

    BankAccount(){

    }


        BankAccount(String n,int b,String a_t) {

            try{
                 ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(3000);
                 Socket s2 = s1.accept();
                 Scanner sc=new Scanner(s2.getInputStream());
                 PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s2.getOutputStream());

                 System.out.println("Connected");

        name=n;
           p.println(name);
           name = sc.nextLine();
           Acc_Balance=b;
         p.println(Acc_Balance);
         Acc_Balance = sc.nextInt();
           acc_type=a_t;
           p.println(name);
           name = sc.nextLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        }


} // end class

class create_account extends BankAccount {



    create_account (String n,int b,String a_t){  

        name=n;
        // name = sc.nextLine();
       //  p.println(name);

         Acc_Balance=b;
        // Acc_Balance=sc.nextInt();
     //    p.println(Acc_Balance);
         acc_type=a_t;
    }
    create_account(){
        super();
    }

    void insert(String n,String a_t){  
        name=n;

        acc_type=a_t;
        Acc_Balance=0;
    }

    void display_details(){
        /*
        try{
             ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
             Socket s2 = s1.accept();
             Scanner sc=new Scanner(s2.getInputStream());
             PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s2.getOutputStream());
             */
                         System.out.println("Depositor Name :" +name);

             System.out.println("Account Balance : "+Acc_Balance);
            // p.println(Acc_Balance);
             System.out.println("Account Type : "+acc_type);
            // p.println(acc_type);

    }

        //deposit money
        void deposit(int money){                 
                Acc_Balance=money;    
        }
        //withdraw money
        int withdraw(int withd){
                Acc_Balance=Acc_Balance-withd;
                return Acc_Balance;
        }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you run a server it waits for client to connect `Socket s2 = s1.accept()`. 
The first thing after that, you're trying to get a name from a client `name = sc.nextLine()`.

As I see from the client code, you are never passing a name to the server. Try to refactor your code to have the same order of writing and reading. Which means, if you're waiting for a name on the server side, the first thing you need to do on the client side  is `p.println(name)`.

Comment: Okay I actually don't need the name or anything in that constructor sorry for the confusion, I just need to pass the account balance,money withdrawn, and money deposited, but that's happening in different methods in the server, so it's like I'd have to make a server for each method, how could I do this with just one server?